# Setting up server to serve files

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I have a server on which there is a Tomcat running and several java aplications are too. Now, I need to do something so that I could fetch files from that server via URL.

I've googled up [`httpd`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/urlmapping.html), yet it seems like it maps ALL urls for the host, which conflicts with my Tomcat. And then again, two web-servers on one machine seems like something conceptually wrong.

The question is, am I right about `httpd` serving all urls, would it be a bad idea to use it and maybe you know a better way to do what I need?

I'm considering making a servlet in tomcat which would somehow respond files to a request or maybe looking up how ftp works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're literally just hosting files, then you can use apache for this alone.  If this is literally all you're doing.

If you have need a java web app, then 100% go for Tomcat (or JBoss if you need it) under the hood.  But I'd say if all you're doing is hosting files, no user login requirements or anything like that, then just use apache.

Comment: Thing is, I alredy have Tomcat apps running. Wouldn't it conflict with apache?

Comment: No, they run on different ports.  If you have multiple tomcat containers then this is something you'll need to configure regarding how apache would delegate down to different tomcats.  If you have Tomcat running by default on 8080, starting an apache on 80 should not conflict.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. Do you know, where I can read some stuff on Apache? It has literally come pass me and I have no idea how to use it :)

Answer (score 1):

Two web servers is normal. First proxy server handle static content (images, js, html pages, etc) and cache it, ans pass all requests for non-static content to main web server ( tomcat in your case )

I recommend you to read about nginx http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html